# trying to write the following line to my tex file

Tags: latex

I am writing my thesis and I am trying to write the following line into my tex file as follows:

```
\textit{LD\_LIBRARY_PATH=~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.12.3-linux64/lib:\$LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH NAO\_IP=10.7.45.53 roslaunch nao\_driver nao\_driver.launch}
```

When I compile I get the following 3 errors:

```
! Missing $ inserted.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.

! Missing $ inserted.
```

The `$` sign I think is creating the problem. Can somebody please show me how I can write the above mentioned line into my tex file? Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, ask (La)TeX-related questions on [tex.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes errors may be a little bit misleading. In your case the real problem is that, same as `$`, the underscore is a reserved character in Latex and to use it you have to use a backslash before it. For more info look at page 5 of this [**Latex Introduction**](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf). So the correct line would be:

```
\textit{LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH=~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.12.3-linux64/lib:\$LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH NAO\_IP=10.7.45.53 roslaunch nao\_driver nao\_driver.launch}
```

Comment: Thanks..I missed the _ . It works now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is not the problem. Your are correctly escaping it. But your underscores have to be escaped as well.

```
\textit{LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH=~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.12.3-linux64/lib:\$LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH NAO\_IP=10.7.45.53 roslaunch nao\_driver nao\_driver.launch}
```

The mentioned missing '$' btw. also is a hint, because using underscores do subscripting in math mode. Also narrowing down the error by trying to remove all of the susceptive code and the piecewise adding it, until the error gets triggered, is how I solve most of my latex problems.

Comment: Thanks..I missed the _ . It works now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.